# regional language support in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, regional

I want to add my regional language(Gujarati) in ionic 1. I used noto gujarati font(https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-gujr) which has been successfully implemented but few OS versions still dont support it, like android 4.2.1. i checked it in different device having android 5.0+, and it is working fine in those device. So  is there any way that it supports all device and OS versions? here my code

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansgujaratiui.css');
.gujarati
{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Gujarati UI', sans-serif;
}
```

One more thing i thought i could do it with iframe. So I uploaded one file with above code and it shows gujarati font in web browser, but when i call it from iframe from my ionic application it doesnt!